# How to make predictions using K-Nearest Neighbors (KNN) model when data has been normalized (Python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, data-science, nearest-neighbor

I have created a KNN model in Python (Module = Scikitlearn) by using three variables (**Age, Distance, Travel Allowance**) as my predictor variables, with the aim of using them to predict an outcome for the target variable (**Method of Travel**).

When constructing the model, I had to normalize the data for the three predictor variables (**Age, Distance, Travel Allowance**). This increased the accuracy of my model compared to not normalizing the data.

Now that I have constructed the model, I want to make a prediction. But how would I enter the predictor variables to make the prediction as the model has been trained on normalized data.

I want to enter `KNN.predict([[30,2000,40]])` to carry out a prediction where Age = 30; Distance = 2000; Allowance = 40. But as the data has been normalized, I can't think of a way on how to do this. I used the following code to normalize the data:
`X = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X).transform(X.astype(float))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the answer is buried in the code you provided!

Once you fit the instance of `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` it remembers how to scale data. Try this

```
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
# scaler is an object that knows how to normalize data points
X_normalized = scaler.transform(X.astype(float))
# used scalar to normalize the data points in X
# Note, this is what you have done, just in two steps. 
# I just capture the scaler object 
#
# ... Train your model on X_normalized
#
# Now predict
other_data = [[30,2000,40]]
other_data_normalized = scaler.transform(other_data)
KNN.predict(other_data_normalized)
```

Notice that I used `scaler.transform` twice in the same way

See [StandardScaler.transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.transform)

Comment: Hi Michael - This works perfectly, thank you! I didn't know that Python remembered the way in which data was normalized.